# Power series - Calculate radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

Let $$\sum {n\over{n+1}} \cdot \left({{2x+1} \over x}\right)^n$$

I was asked to calculate the radius of convergence. We can write the series as:

$$\sum {n\over {n+1}}\cdot \left(2+{1\over x}\right)^n$$

Now, we can define $t:={2+{1\over x}}$ and then evaluate the series $\displaystyle\sum {n\over {n+1}}\cdot t^n$.

Is there another way I'm expected to think of without using this "trick"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take root test, 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt [n] { \left| \frac{n}{n+1} \cdot \left( \frac{2x+1}{x}\right)^n \right |} < 1$$ 
$$  \mathrm{or, }\frac{1}{\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^{\frac 1 n}} \left| \frac{2x+1}{x}\right| < 1 $$